# Why won't my class variable change to a textbox's text?

Tags: swift, class

I'm writing simple function that aims to write the contents of some text boxes into the variables in an instance of a class.

When I try and print the contents of the text box, it works. The contents are there.

I've tried connecting the text boxes to the button that runs the function.

Here are some of the parent and child classes:

```
class RapName {
    var numberProper: String
    var nameProper: String
    ...

    init(){
        self.numberProper = "number proper"
        self.nameProper = "name proper"
        ...
    }
}

class rapNameStyle: RapName {

    var twoChainzStyle: (String, String, String)?
    var tinyTimTheRapperStyle: (String, String, String, String, String)?
   ...
    var allStyles: [Any]?


    override init (){
    super.init()
        self.twoChainzStyle = (numberProper, " ", noun)
        self.tinyTimTheRapperStyle = (adjective, " ", nameProper, " the ", noun)
       ...
        self.allStyles = [twoChainzStyle!, bigSnitchStyle!, crunchyBlackStyle!, tinyTimTheRapperStyle! as Any, zaeTheBlacksmithStyle!,
                     littleRichardStyle!,drDreStyle!, poetPeteStyle!, notoriousBIGStyle!, flavaFlavStyle!, mrHappyStyle!, captainPotatoStyle!, stevensShakinStyle!] as [Any]    
    }

}
```

Here is the function:

```
@IBAction func buttonPress(_ sender: Any) {
    rapName.nameProper = textBox1.text!
    rapName.numberProper = textBox2.text!
    rapName.verb = allVerbs.randomElement()!
    rapName.noun = allNouns.randomElement()!
    rapName.adjective = allAdjectives.randomElement()!
    rapName.secondAdjective = allAdjectives.randomElement()!
    rapName.secondNoun = allNouns.randomElement()!
    rapName.acronym = textBox4.text!
    rapName.titleProper = textBox3.text!

    let randomStyle = rapName.allStyles?.randomElement()
    let finalString = String("\(randomStyle)")
...
        rapNameLabel.text = finalString
    }
    }
```

The goal is for a rap name with a random style to be displayed which contains the contents of the text boxes.

However, only the original initialised variable in the random rap name style is returned.

So, for example if the text box for adjective contains "little" and the text box for name proper contains "wiggles" and the random style littlerichardstyle is chosen the lable should display "little wiggles" instead it just displays "adjective" "name proper" (from the initialiser).

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you show how you instantiate rap name var ? Is it RapName or RapNameStyle (should start with uppercase)

Comment: The problem is that allStyles is never modified

Comment: Thank you helping. It is instantiated with var rapName = rapNameStyle(). I will use upper case to fit with convention, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make all var in RapNameStyle be computed properties:

```
class RapNameStyle: RapName {
    var twoChainzStyle: (String, String, String)? {
        return (numberProper, " ", noun)
    }
    var tinyTimTheRapperStyle: (String, String, String, String, String)? {
        return (adjective, " ", nameProper, " the ", noun)
    }
    // Same for others
    var allStyles: [Any]? {
        return [twoChainzStyle!, bigSnitchStyle!, crunchyBlackStyle!, tinyTimTheRapperStyle! as Any, zaeTheBlacksmithStyle!,
         littleRichardStyle!,drDreStyle!, poetPeteStyle!, notoriousBIGStyle!, flavaFlavStyle!, mrHappyStyle!, captainPotatoStyle!, stevensShakinStyle!]
    }
}
```

Then init() is just super.init()

Consider the very simple following example:

```
class ASuper {
    var top: Int

    init() {
        top = 1
    }
}

class BSub: ASuper {
    var under: Int?
    var all: [Any]?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.under = 10
        self.all = [under!]
    }

}

let b = BSub()
b.under = 200

print(b.all!)
```

You get [10] and not [200]
When you change the value of b.under to 200, all is not reevaluated, it is still [10]. It will be with a computed var.

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked. Your time and skills are appreciated :)